# Setting Hostname on jsDAV

Tags: node.js, webdav

I am using jsDAV.

When using it locally or on my server(xx.xx.xx.xx), it is running successfully at 127.0.0.1:8000.

I would like to change the HOST to my server IP i.e. "xx.xx.xx.xx:8000". How can I do this?

I have tried passing my IP as the third param in the

```
jsDAV.createServer(options, 8000, "xx.xx.xx.xx");
```

When I explicitly put "127.0.0.1", it works fine. As soon as I put in my IP, I get

```
Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL
```

After looking up "EADDRNOTAVAIL", I changed my port to 32769 and still get the same error.

Any ideas as to how I can access my server as "xx.xx.xx.xx:32769"

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

Here it is incase anyone else needs it.

You just need to replace your IP address with 0.0.0.0 along with an available port number.

So, it would look something like this:

```
jsDAV.createServer(options, 8000, "0.0.0.0");
```

This worked!